# How to add data into an array using inputs in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and I am trying to build a todo app which basically can execute the CRUD operation. I am able to update and delete as of now. But not sure how to create an object and save it into the array.

When i click on edit or add task button a modal pop up and i am trying to enter the title and description value there.

This is my Index.js file

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Button, Modal } from 'reactstrap';
import Modals from './Modals'


const todoItems = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Go to Market",
    description: "Buy ingredients to prepare dinner",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Study",
    description: "Read Algebra and History textbook for upcoming test",
    completed: false
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Sally's books",
    description: "Go to library to rent sally's books",
    completed: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Article",
    description: "Write article on how to use django with react",
    completed: false
  }
];


class Index extends Component {
  state = { 
      modal: false,
      items: todoItems,
      selectedItem: null,
      selectedIndex: -1,
   }

    toggle = (item, index) => {
    if (item) {
     this.setState({ selectedItem: item, selectedIndex: index })
    }
    this.setState({ modal: !this.state.modal });
    };

    handleChange = () => {
      let oldState = this.state.items;
      this.setState({ items: oldState })
    }

    onDelete = (item) => {
      const newData = this.state.items.filter(i => i.title !== item.title)
      this.setState({ items: newData })
    }



  render() { 
    return ( 
      <>
      <h1 className="p-3">TODO APP</h1>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "white", padding: "50px", color: "black"}} className="container">
        <div className="row">
        <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={() =>  this.toggle()}>Add task</button>
        </div>
        <div className="row my-5">
        <Button color="danger mr-5">Incomplete</Button>
        <Button color="success">Complete</Button>
        <Modals index={this.state.selectedIndex} onDelete={this.onDelete}  item={this.state.selectedItem} handleChange={this.handleChange} modal={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} />

        </div>
        <hr/>
        {this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
          return(
            <div key={item.id}>
            <div className="row">
            <p style={{ textAlign: "left" }}>{item.title}</p>
              <Button onClick={() =>  this.toggle(item, index)} className="mr-0 ml-auto" color="info">Edit</Button>
              <Button onClick={() => this.onDelete(item)} className="ml-5" color="warning">Delete</Button>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            
            </div>
            )
          })}
      </div>
      </>
     );
  }
}
 
export default Index;
```

This is my modal.js file

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';

function Modals(props) {

    const {
        className,
        buttonLabel,
        handleChange,
        item,
        index,
        toggle,
      } = props;
    
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
      if (item && item.title){
      setTitle(item.title)
      setDescription(item.description)
    }
    }, [item])
  

    const setValues = () => {
      handleChange({ title: title, description: description });
      props.toggle();
      push({

      })
    }


    return (
        <div>
      <Modal isOpen={props.modal} className={className} style={{ color: "black"}}>
        <ModalHeader >Todo Item</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>
          <div className="container-fluid">
              <div className="row mb-3">
                  <div className="col-12">
                    <p className="mb-0">Title</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-12">
                      <input onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)} value={title} className="w-100" type="text" placeholder="Enter title"/>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row mb-3">
                  <div className="col-12">
                    <p className="mb-0">Description</p>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-12">
                      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} value={description} className="w-100" placeholder="Enter Description"/>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-12">
                    <input type="checkbox"/>
                   <span className="ml-2"> Completed </span>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button onClick={() => setValues()}  color="success">Submit</Button>
          <Button onClick={props.toggle} color="secondary">Cancel</Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    </div>
    )
  }


  export default Modals;
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to just create a method in index.js

```
addItem = (item) =>{
  this.setState({items: [...this.state.items, item]})
}
```

and then just pass it as a prop to your Modal and call it in setValues,

```
const setValues = () => {
  handleChange({ title: title, description: description });
  props.toggle();
  props.addItem({ title: title, description: description, //etc})
}
```

Comment: This works. But could you let me know what are you trying to do with the code inside index.js? If i am not wrong i understand you are trying to copy the state.items using spread operator and assigning it to a variable. But what does the comma item do?

Comment: That appends item to the copied array